# How do you handle when you have too many tabs in your masterpage of your application?

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, tabs, repeater

Actually I think it is a bit design issue.

Question is, if you have programmatically generated tabs -let's say by using repeater control- at the top of your masterpage, how do you handle them after you have too many -so that they do not overlap the view-port of the browser?

I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there are already some patterns for such an issue.

Any recommendations?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your tabs are going to be dynamic you should probably move them to a vertical side bar as opposed to a horizontal tab, this would make it more scalable. To maintain a consistent look and feel its probably a good idea to have static main tabs at the top with dynamic associated vertical tabs. Not sure if this helps at all?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain a horizontal layout, you will need to reduce the nav to viewable items and have some sort of < and > at the left and right edges of the nav to enable the user to scroll to the prior or next viewable set.

Not sure if this is what you are looking for.